# Слово "пункт" в старославянском языке

Tags: этимология, славянизмы

Каким словом обозначалось понятие "пункт" раньше?

Comment: У слова “пункт” много значений, и по каждому из них нужно искать синоним, употребляемый в прошлом.

Answer (score 1):

А какое значение этого слова интересует? Если населённый пункт - то раньше это было село - место поселения.

Как указывает Фасмер, здесь произошла контаминация слов selo «жилище, селение, пашня» (родственного др.-в.-нем. sal «дом, жилище», лат. solum «поле, земля») и  *sedlo «поселение» с суф. -dlo,( ср. чешск. sidlo «местонахождение, сидение») от той же основы, что сесть ( *sedti) . Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Было ещё слово весь - (города и веси) - из древнерусского вьсь (деревня, село).

Но это не старославянское слово, а русское с праславянским корнем *vьsь.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "пункт" — заимствованное. Вот что говорится о нем в этимологическом словаре русского языка [**М. Фасмера**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-10590.htm):

**ПУНКТ**
род. п. -а, начиная с Ф. Прокоповича, 1698 г. (Христиани 29; Смирнов 249). Через польск. *punkt* или нем. *Punkt* (**с 1571 г.**, Шульц–Баслер 2, 734) из лат. *punctum* "точка, пункт": *pungō* "ставить точку".

**ПУНКТЪ (ПУНТЪ)**, м.

**1.** Пункт, статья (договора).
А про казачие, государь, трактаты, на чемъ козаки съ королемъ трактаты чинятъ ... и тѣ, государь, многие статьи сошлись съ тѣми пунктами, что я холопъ твой писалъ къ тебѣ... напередъ сего. ДАИ IV, 136. 1658 г.
А в Кардинском уставлено мирном договоре в дватцатом пункте написано, что... полонных людей назад отдавать). Поруб. д., 146. 1663 г.
II Мн. Об условиях договора.
Писалъ къ намъ... воевода Василий... Шереметевъ съ товарыщи и прислалъ пунты ваши... и мы, великий государь 
христианский, не желая пролития крови вашея, пожаловали васъ. Статьи Шерем., 736. 1655 г.
А з бояриномъ нашимъ договаривалися о пунтахъ. Там же, 737.

**2.** В линейной нотации — точка при ноте, увеличивающая ее длительность наполовину. Пунктъ, сирѣчь точка, когда стоитъ при двухъ тактах, есть тактъ, когда при тактѣ есть полтакта. Мусик. грам. Дил. 1, 147. 1679 г.
[**Словарь русского языка XI–XVII вв.**](https://archive.org/stream/B-001-004-150/xi-xvii_21_djvu.txt)

Comment: Это интересно, но не отвечает на вопрос.